# How can I solve this error when I try to download e(fx)clipse from Eclipse Marketplace into my Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, javafx, eclipse-marketplace

It says installing software has encountered a problem.

Here are the details:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: e(fx)clipse - IDE 3.5.0.201907240300 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.feature.feature.group 3.5.0.201907240300)
Missing requirement: JDT UI Tooling for JavaFX 3.5.0.201907240300 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.jdt.ui 3.5.0.201907240300) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.emf.databinding 1.2.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: e(fx)clipse - IDE - Basic 3.5.0.201907240300 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.basic.feature.feature.group 3.5.0.201907240300)
To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.fx.ide.jdt.ui [3.5.0.201907240300,3.5.0.201907240300]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: e(fx)clipse - IDE 3.5.0.201907240300 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.feature.feature.group 3.5.0.201907240300)
To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.fx.ide.basic.feature.feature.group [3.5.0.201907240300,3.5.0.201907240300]
```

I have no clue what to do because I started from a clean Eclipse download with the latest version.

This error didn't happen before I uninstalled Eclipse.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
Build id: 20201210-1552

Comment: Which Eclipse IDE package do you have (what says the _About_ dialog: _Eclipse IDE for ..._?)?

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
Build id: 20201210-1552

this is what it says

Answer (score 1):

hi if the marketplace didn't work try to install it from "install new software" in help
after past this URL:http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-nightly/site
and then chose e(fx)clipse-install